# Add padding to all childs except last

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am trying to add `padding` to all child elements of a `div` except the last one.

I tried using the negation for `last-child` but it doesn't even add `padding` to the rest of the child elements when I use that...

**Here is my HTML:**

```css
#container .description:not(:last-child) {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Description</div>
    <div class="description">Description 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Description</div>
    <div class="description">Description 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Description</div>
    <div class="description">Description 2</div>
  </div>
  Testing here
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1xm8Lxom/1/)**

Comment: All `.description` elements *are* the `:last-child` of their parents; therefore your selector selects no elements and so applies no styling.

Comment: If you're willing to change your markup: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AEhFb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following rule should be what you're looking for. It will add 10px of padding to all descriptions except the one in the last `.box` element:

```
#container .box:not(:last-child) .description{
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdvk6mr0/1/)

Comment: Is there any way I can use a negation? Kinda like I tried?

Comment: @imbondbaby Changed the answer to use negation, but negation isn't necessary (unless you really want just one rule)

Comment: Thank you so much! That works and I see how as well! Will accept the answer when I can

Comment: Cleanest solution - unless IE7/8 is a strict requirment. `E7 and IE8 support only these CSS3 selectors: General siblings (element1~element2) and Attribute selectors [attr^=val], [attr$=val], and [attr*=val]` - [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child)

Answer (score 3):

You presumably want:

```css
#container .description {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#container > :last-child .description {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

As your selector is currently written:

```css
#container .description:not(:last-child){
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

It fails to match any elements because all the `.description` elements are the last-child of their parent elements.

In response to comments, a needlessly complex (and limited cross-browser compatible) approach using the negation operator:

```css
#container .box:not(:last-child) .description {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use a negation? Kinda like I tried?

Comment: And why do you want to use the negation operator unnecessarily? I mean: yes, of course there is, but *why?*

Answer (score 2):

What about using `:last-child` instead, it is simple, and doesn't need to use the negation selector `:not`(which has less support than `:first/last-child`).

```css
#container .box:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

### snippet

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid
}

#container .box {
  padding-bottom: 10px
}

#container .box:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Description</div>
    <div class="description">Description 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Description</div>
    <div class="description">Description 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="title">Description</div>
    <div class="description">Description 2</div>
  </div>
  Testing here
</div>
```